# Swift Timer not working properly for old iPhone models

Tags: swift, concurrency, timer

I am getting a problem with Swift timer. Timer are not working properly for old iPhone models like iPhone 6. When I printed out time, timer counts every 2 second as 1 second. But if i change withTimeInterval as 0.05, it works a bit better. But still is not work as real life time. Here is my code. Can anyone help me ?

```
weak var timer: Timer?
var startTime : TimeInterval!
var elapsingTime: Double = 0.0

func configureTimer(totalSecond: Double) {

    startTime = Date().timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate
    self.invalidateTimer()

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.02,target: self,selector: #selector(self.advanceTimer(timer:)),userInfo: nil,repeats: true)

    }

}

@objc func advanceTimer(timer: Timer) {

    elapsingTime += 0.02

    self.questionView.configureProgressBar(totalTime: Double(self.totalSecond), elapsingTime: elapsingTime)
    self.isTimeExpired = false

    self.elapsingTime = Date().timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate - self.startTime

    if Int(elapsingTime) == Int(totalSecond) {

        self.timer!.invalidate()
        self.isTimeExpired = true
        self.userAnswerIndex = -1
        self.sendAnswer(index: self.userAnswerIndex, isTimeExpired: self.isTimeExpired)
    }
}
```

Comment: What call are you making that is not working correctly?

Comment: `0.01`s is way too frequent. Not only does timer precision decrease for such short time-spans, but it also nails the CPU with frequent wake-ups and kills battery. You should consider an alternative solution.

Comment: Timer not working as real time @HalR

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica what do you suggest? ı tried everything

Comment: The older models are probably not coping well with that short of time interval.  That is way too frequent for them to be interrupted.  The iphone screen refresh interval is .016667.  You are interrupting more quickly than that.

Comment: @HalR Well why do you need to tell the `questionView.videoQuestionPlayer` to play 100 times a second?

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica i updated my latest code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Timers are not very precise. There precisions is about 0.05 seconds I think. And if a process require a lot of power, your timer will be even more slowed down. The solution can be to save the time when you start your timer and that each time your timer fire, you do a mathematical operation to know how many time passed :

```
class YourClass {

var startTime : TimeInterval!

//...

func configureTimer() {
    startTime = Date().timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate //You add this line

    elapsingTime = 0.0
    timer?.invalidate()

    DispatchQueue.main.async {

        self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.01, repeats: true, block: { [weak self] timer in

            guard let self = self else { return }

            self.elapsingTime = Date().timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate - self.startTime //You change this one
            self.questionView.configureProgressBar(totalTime: self.totalTime, elapsingTime: self.elapsingTime)
            self.questionView.videoQuestionPlayer.player?.play()
            if Int(self.elapsingTime) == Int(self.totalTime) {

                self.timer!.invalidate()
                self.isTimeExpired = true
                self.sendAnswer(index: -1)
            }
        })
    }
}
```

}

Comment: thanks. I updated my code like on my question. It works ! :)

Answer (score 0):

I would try setting it up like this.

```
var myTimer = Timer()
var counter = 0.0

myTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.1, target: self, selector: #selector(yourTargetFunctionHere), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

@objc func yourTargetFunctionHere() { 
     //in here is where you do all your code work
     counter += 0.1
     if counter == yourElapsedTime {
         //when your target time is hit do something here
     }
     if counter == finishedTime {
       self.timer.invalidate()
       self.counter = 0
     }
}
```

Comment: He could do this but he would not have the precision he want...